# Joining with linq

Tags: linq, join

I have the following linq statement. It is returning everything from allStores. I removed the DefaultIfEmpty and then it only returned the stores that are in both the subs table AND the allStores table. I need it to return all stores that are in subs table even if they are not in the allStores table. I have tried a few different things and have moved around the defaultifempty but can't seem to get it to return what I need.

I need stores 1,2,4,5 returned (everything in table 2) and I need to pull the division ID for the storeId from table 3 and the address from table 3. Even if the store is not in the address table or not in divisionID table I still need the storeID returned in the query.

```
from a in allStores
   join sub in subs on a.DivisionId equals sub.DivisionId
   join d in divs on new { a.DivisionId, a.StoreId } equals new { d.DivisionId, d.StoreId } into s
   from selected in s.DefaultIfEmpty()
```

| StoreId | Address |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1234 Elm St. |
| 2 | 5678 Maple St. |
| 3 | 9101 Bella Ave. |
| 4 | 1234 Meadow Dr. |

| StoreId | StoreStatus |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Closed |
| 2 | Open |
| 4 | Open |
| 5 | Open |

| StoreId | DivisionId |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 12 |
| 2 | 14 |
| 3 | 16 |
| 4 | 18 |
| 5 | 20 |

Comment: please add some example data

Comment: The first table in the `from` statement needs to contain all the items that you want included then the others have the `DefaultIfEmpty'. Some sample data and expected results would help

Comment: I added some example data

Comment: Your sample data is incomplete and cannot be used with your code.   As you mentioned in your comment to my answer you watered it down.  But you can't water it down so much that your code doesn't make sense.  Consider revising.

Comment: Actually, your statement above "The first table in the from statement needs to contain all the items that you want included then the others have the `DefaultIfEmpty'" is exactly what I needed. So that helped me out. I got it working now after I did that.

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for multiple left joins.  I've noticed that in this area of questions there are a lot of near duplicates.  But many of these only discuss one left join, others don't describe a need to deal with null reference exceptions, and still others describe linq-to-sql or similar and not linq-to-objects, which seems to be your case here.

Your sample data is not complete, so I'm just going to trust that you are joining on the right fields.  You're close with your join on `divs`.  But you need to do the same thing for `subs`, and you need to add a `select` segment that outputs the final shape of each row extracting properties from each source.

```
var results = 

    from a in allStores

    // left join allScores with "subs"
    join sub in subs on a.DivisionId equals sub.DivisionId into subG
    from sub in subG.DefaultIfEmpty()

    // left join allScores with divs
    join div in divs 
        on new { a.DivisonId, a.StoreId } 
        equals new { div.DivisionId, div.StoreId } 
        into divG
    from div in divG.DefaultIfEmpty() 

    // select properties from all sources, keeping in mind some are null
    select new { 
        a.StoreId, 
        a.StoreStatus,
        sub?.Address,  // if you have a newer version of c#
        DivisonId = div == null ? null : (int?)div.DivisionId // if you have an older version of c#
    };
```

Comment: Well, I watered down the "data" example just to make life easier but I do need to join on store and division id the way our data is structured. There is a lot more data elements to this that I didnt include for simplicity's sake. I just need to get this linq statement modified to include all the stores in subs no matter what and to only pull the address and division data when it is available.

Comment: So DivisionId exists in all tables?  And each store has can have multiple divisions but each division can only have one store?

Comment: Okay, edited.  Let me know if it meets your needs.

Comment: This helped a lot with a little tweaking it is working now. Thanks.

Comment: That's good to hear.  Consider accepting the answer if it helped you out.